# c# class, method or what to parse a config file

Tags: c#, parsing, class, methods, call

New to the object orientated method of doing things and was just wondering what is the suggested method for doing this.

in my first question I asked about parsing a text file, and now with some good ideas (thank you guys) I am starting to write this part of the program.

the text file has multiple sections and multiple data types needed to be read in. This is going fine and as the complexity of the text file grows so the I am changing the code to adapt. But I will end up with 30 or so different variables/arrays/list etc that at least some will need to be global available to the program.

So I now have a chunk of code that at the moment is a method within the class that contains "main", and all the variables are global. (not nice I know).

I was thinking there must be a neater way to do this, I was thinking use a separate class, create an instance of this class and call the method with in this class that parses the text and populates the variables. Then simple call the class variables (any ones deemed to be public)from with in any other class I need to.

But then what do I know :) just looking for some ideas so i don't go to far down the road and have to turn back.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instincts are good; the task of parsing a particular type of text file should be encapsulated in a class that is given some information about where to get the data, and produces an object graph representing the parsed data. As far as the input, a string with the filename is fine; better yet, pass in a Stream or StreamReader; the same parser can then digest the information from a file, memory block or network transmission.

Definitely break things down into repeatable chunks; if a file consists of a lot of similar lines that are parsed into subobjects, create a method to parse a single line and return the subobject.

Also make things as single-purpose as possible; if you have to deal with two types of text files, create one class for each file type, making them implement the same interface if possible. Then, you can implement what's called a Strategy pattern, where one object's job is to determine which of a series of other classes should be used to perform a task depending on the specifics.

Comment: `Global_varible_int tesst = new Global_varible_int();  
            tesst.parse();  
            int mul = tesst.multi(10);  
            int numer = tesst.Number;  
            Console.WriteLine(numer);
            Console.WriteLine(mul); ` very simple bit of code to test this, now the "parse" method with in the class is the one that would do the actuly parsing (only want to parse the file once when creating the instance, or if manualy refreshed). is this the best way  to do it, or is it possible to create an instance of a class and excyuate a method in one go?

Comment: its funny how starting this project the idea of parsing a text file was not on my mind. but the whole point of this now is that, it will make the final application extremal flexible an user friendly. How little code can i use to get the most amount of work done with out sacrificing userbility:)

Answer (score 1):

If the format for the config file is not set in stone, then I would suggest utilizing the System.Xml.XmlSerializer class to save/load your config file as xml.

Pretty simple to save.. load will be left as an excersize for you:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.something, FileShare.something))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.getType());
    serializer.serialize(file, this);
}
```

I may have goofed up the order of the parameters, and I'm a vb guy, but you get the idea.

Comment: Good idea, but note you will have to create a class to encapsulate all the global variables (or whatever) and pass that class name to `GetType`.

Answer (score 1):

To keep things simple, I would use the [serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class to do it:

Here is the example Config classes:

```
[Serializable]
public class Config
{
    public int ValueOne { get; set; }
    public string ValueTwo { get; set; }
    public int[] LotsOfValues { get; set; }
    public List<FurtherConfig> Other { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class FurtherConfig 
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

And here is some example usage:

```
var config = new Config
{
    ValueOne = 23,
    ValueTwo = "Second Value",
    LotsOfValues = new[] { 23, 34, 34 },
    Other = new List<FurtherConfig> {
        new FurtherConfig { Value = 567},
        new FurtherConfig { Value = 98 }
    }
};

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Config));

//write out to file
using (var fw = File.OpenWrite("config.xml"))
    serializer.Serialize(fw, config);

//read in from file
Config newConfig;
using (var fr = File.OpenRead("config.xml"))
    newConfig = serializer.Deserialize(fr) as Config;

Console.WriteLine(newConfig.Other[1].Value); //prints 98
```

This is the serialized output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ValueOne>23</ValueOne>
  <ValueTwo>Second Value</ValueTwo>
  <LotsOfValues>
    <int>23</int>
    <int>34</int>
    <int>34</int>
  </LotsOfValues>
  <Other>
    <FurtherConfig>
      <Value>567</Value>
    </FurtherConfig>
    <FurtherConfig>
      <Value>98</Value>
    </FurtherConfig>
  </Other>
</Config>
```

Comment: I like the XML idea, but as I am only reading in a file and I want users to be able to edit it as they see fit. XML would be a bit tricky.

Comment: What about the BinaryFormatter in place of the XmlSerializer class? It should work in the same way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For the parsing, I agree that XML serialization is a good way to do things.

As for how to access the data once it's in an object, consider a [static class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: the things you learn, so that's what the static keyword is for :) Perfect!! I love it as things fall in to place :)